# Meaning of 'as it were' in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of 'as it were' in the below excerpt, which is from Tolkien's Unfinished Tales (p. 350, USA edition)

> For
> this reason also Saruman ceased to go thither [to the Shire] in person; for it came to his
> knowledge that he had not been all unobserved by the keen-eyed Halflings,
> and some, seeing the figure **as it were** of an old man clad in grey or russet stealing through the woods or passing through the dusk, had mistaken him
> for Gandalf.

'As it were' does not here seem to mark what is said as metaphorical, which is its usual purpose.

Comment: The phrasing is unusual / mock-archaic in many respects. Specifically, most speakers / writers would probably say / write *...seeing the figure **as if it was** [the figure] of an old man clad in grey*. I don't think "metaphor" is a relevant term here, but ***as it it was / were*** functions like ***like*** here, so you could say there's something of a "simile" involved.

Comment: (I thought Saruman ***was*** "an old man clad in grey", but that wouldn't make sense here. Perhaps this "Unfinished Tale" concerns what Saruman got up to in his youth! :)

Comment: Thanks. If I may correct you, however: This particular 'unfinished tale' does not concern the events of Saruman's youth, but the events leading up to the LOTR. Unfortunately, I cannot explain in detail the context behind this tale, since that would require considerable foreknowledge of the LOTR mythology on your behalf (forgive my impertinence if I am mistaken, and you are indeed conversant with LOTR mythology). However, having the book at my fingertips, I am inclined to believe that your analysis is indeed correct. So thank you; and I must apologize for my propensity to pontificate.

Comment: It was over 50 years ago when I read the books, and I fell asleep during one of the interminable battle scenes in the only movie I started, so my knowledge of the details is hazy at best. But ***as if*** and ***as it were*** always imply X is ***like*** Y, not that X ***really is*** Y. So far as I recall, Gandalf was *always* "old" and "cloaked", even in "prequel" stories. But in your cited context, Saruman *can't* have been old / grey / cloaked (it makes no sense to say he *looked like* an old man if he really *was* an old man).

Comment: I agree with you that 'as it were' is here used to indicate that the image of Saruman the 'keen-eyed Halflings' saw was not his actual figure. However, it was not his being old that they misperceived, but rather his being clad in grey/russet, since he was still very old at that time (having entered Middle-Earth a thousand or so years before, and having lived in Valinor before that for an even greater time).

Comment: Hmm. That reading doesn't work for me - that he was only *like* (not *actually*) a grep/russet cloaked old man, because although he was an old man, his cloak was a different colour. Perhaps that's why it's only an "Unfinished Tale" (that Tolkien would have at least *rephrased* before publication).

Answer (score 2):

"as it were" is a set expression that is used by writers to acknowledge they they have not necessarily provided the best phrase for what they have just said in their own opinion.

[...] seeing the figure, as it were, of an old man

It is not clear to me why the author says as it were here, but he does. He apparently feels that the word "figure" is not necessarily the best.

Another way to describe this is to say it can also mean: for want of a better term.